# How to "group by" renamed fild in ms - access

Tags: ms-access

I have this select working good in access

```
 select case when ziffer = '042'  then 0 else 1 end as ID,
        case when ziffer = '042'  then 'Fiktiv' else 'Regelbesteuert' end as Code 
 from MWST_Code
```

if I try to group this select by ID and Code I keep an error

Comment: Would this perchance be a pass-through query to SQL Server?

Comment: No, in sql is working this query

 
   *** " select case when ziffer = '042' then 0 else 1 end as ID
    from MWST_Code group by ID " ***

but in access don't work

Comment: Well then I'm confused because when I copy and paste your SQL into an Access query and try to run it I get `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'case when ziffer = '042' then 0 else 1 end'.` Access SQL does not support the `CASE` construct.

Comment: is not right, ms-access sport case statment but access do not know renamed fild, if is access you can use *** " IIF(condition, valueiftrue, valueiffalse) " ***

Comment: you can look here http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php

Comment: That's the `Select Case` construct in VBA, not the `CASE ... THEN ... ELSE` construct that *does* work in T-SQL (SQL Server) but does *not* work in Access SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you access support case statment try to do group so:

```
 select case when ziffer = '042'  then 0 else 1 end as ID, 
      case when ziffer = '042'  then 'Fiktiv' else 'Regelbesteuert' end as Code
      from MWST_Code 
      group by case when ziffer = '042'  then 0 else 1 end, 
           case when ziffer = '042'  then 'Fiktiv' else 'Regelbesteuert' end
```